# broadcom B4318 driver installation - cannot unload wl driver in 14.04

Tags: broadcom

linux newbie problem:

/i've installed 14.04 on an acer aspire laptop and cannot get the wifi to work (no wifi symbol in taskbar even).

I've tried following the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

```
lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network 0a:05.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4318] (rev 02)

Subsystem: AMBIT Microsystem Corp. TravelMate 2410 [1468:0312]  Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-   Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort-  <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-

Latency: 32 Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 20   Region 0: Memory at d0004000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Kernel driver in use: wl

0a:06.0 CardBus bridge [0607]: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 Cardbus Controller [104c:8039]
```

not sure that's pasted in right so I summarise:
broadcom BCM4318
picid:[14e4:4318]
kernel driver in use:wl

So I tried following the instructions down the page to install the B43 using the open-source firmware-B43-installer, and restarted, but that didn't solve the problem.

so I tried the next bit:

> 2.04 (Precise Pangolin) - 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) Open a Terminal and if you haven't already done so, update your package list:
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> If you have a b43 card use the command
>
> sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer

and restarted, again with no improvement, so to the next bit:

> Switching between drivers
>
> If you card is supported by more than one driver then use the modprobe
>   command to test the drivers. First unload all conflicting drivers
>   (this includes removing the driver you're trying to install):
>
> sudo modprobe -r b43 bcma
>
> sudo modprobe -r brcmsmac bcma
>
> sudo modprobe -r wl
>
> To load a specific driver use one of the following commands:
>
> sudo modprobe b43
>
> sudo modprobe brcmsmac
>
> sudo modprobe wl
>
> Allow several seconds for the network manager to scan for available
>   networks before attempting a connection.

this is where I got stuck - the 1st two sudo modprobe -r commands were fine but when I try and remove the wl driver I get:

> modprobe: FATAL: Module wl is in use.

I cannot see how to proceed from here so I would appreciate some direction.

```
rfkill list 0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN  Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no

sudo iwconfig
[sudo] password for a: 
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

not sure what other info I need to supply (complete linux newbie sorry). ethernet (wired) internet is working OK.
Thx

Comment: According to that howto, bcm4318 is only supported by the b43 driver. Why then, do you have STA installed?

Comment: hi mikewhatever; if you don't mind me asking, how did you figure out that the STA driver was installed? - I'd swear that Ididn't install it and could only see 'wl'.

Comment: Thanks clili555 for giving this newbie the answer I needed - much appreciated.

Comment: It's the wl module. It is provided by the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package, aka Broadcom STA. You must have had it installed at some point.

Comment: For some reason the B43 driver was blacklisted - now I know I didn't do that. Just one more thing: the wireless LED on the laptop now flickers on and off as the (now working) wifi is used - in winXP it just stayed on - is this normal, or have I got something else to straighten out?

Comment: Thanks mike - it's a new install so must have installed by default I guess - rather confusing that it id's as wl not bcmwl though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot and enjoy your wireless.